# logging.info not print on terminal

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

my pytest.ini config as

```
[pytest]
log_cli=True
log_cli_level=INFO
......
```

conftest.py define 2 fixture

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def dut():
    dut = Dut()
    dut.init()
    yield dut
    dut.deinit()

@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def dut_info(request, dut):
    ......
    dut.collect_info()
    yield
    if request.node.rep_call.failed:
        ......
        dut.dump_fail_info()
    ......
    dut.collect_info()
```

then, logging.info cannot print on terminal.

if set dut_info autouse to False, logging.info can print on terminal normally.
if not use dut fixture, like

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def dut_info(request):
    ......
    yield
    if request.node.rep_call.failed:
        ......
    ......
```

logging.info can print on terminal normally too.

I do not know why and what to do with this.
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this

i try to find the reason of this is one autouse fixture using another fixure, but i don't know why.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what is `Dud` and what does it do?

Comment: Dut is a "Device under test", its a class, bring device acitve or inactive.

Comment: I'm asking because it looks like initializing `Dut` shuts down logging, so without seeing what it actually does it's difficult to say anything here.

Comment: someone reset logging level by mistake in another module, and without informing us. Thanks for your help anyway. ^ ^